# How to remove item from list without deleting it in Android?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite

I am new to Android and My question is I have created a method "Mark As Completed" when I am clicking on it, it set true value into the database. What I want now is when I click on mark as completed that item deleted from the list but not from the database. Is it possible?

EDIT:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
    addTasklist = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.addTasklist);
    taskList_completed = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.completedflag);
    Button ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
    ok.setOnClickListener(this);
    list();
    }
public void list(){
    db = new TodoTask_Database(getApplicationContext());
    list_tasklistname = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
    list = db.getAllTaskList();
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(Main_Activity.this, R.layout.tasklist_row, list);
    list_tasklistname.setAdapter(adapter);
    db.close();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    registerForContextMenu(list_tasklistname);

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    Position = info.position;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
case R.id.MarkAsCompleted:
        db = new TodoTask_Database(getApplicationContext());
        task = adapter.getItem(Position);
        int taskList_Id = task.getTaskListId();
        // here is database method which is setting item value true when mark as completed on long click listener is pressed.
db.Complete_TaskList(taskList_Id);              
        break;
        }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

My Custom list Adapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Task> {

    private List<Task> dataitem;
    private Activity activity;
    TodoTask_Database db;

public CustomAdapter(Activity a, int textViewResourceId, List<Task> items) {
    super(a, textViewResourceId, items);
    this.dataitem = items;
    this.activity = a;
}

public static class ViewHolder{
    public TextView tasklistTitle;
    public TextView createdDate;
    public CheckBox completedflag;
}

   @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi =
            (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.tasklist_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tasklistTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tasklistTitle);
        holder.createdDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.createdDate);
        holder.completedflag = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.completedflag);
        v.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
        holder=(ViewHolder)v.getTag();

    final Task custom = dataitem.get(position);
    if (custom != null) {
        holder.tasklistTitle.setText(custom.getTaskListTitle());
        holder.createdDate.setText(custom.getTaskListCreated());
        holder.completedflag.setText(custom.getTaskListCompletedFlag());
    }
    return v;
}
   public synchronized void refresAdapter(List<Task> dataitems) {
    dataitem.clear();
    dataitem.addAll(dataitems);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
}
```

Comment: Remove that item from list adapter..

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to do that in my custom list adapter. but failure.

Comment: post what you have done

Comment: Remove object in your list-dat, and after that call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged`.Hope this helps.

Comment: I have edited my question and posted my code, please check now.

Comment: @PankajKumar I have edited my question, Any suggestion now, how to remove items in adapter where value is set true in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
list.remove(Position); // Remove item from List
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Notify adapter
```

at `case R.id.MarkAsCompleted`. Like below

```
case R.id.MarkAsCompleted:
        db = new TodoTask_Database(getApplicationContext());
        task = adapter.getItem(Position);
        int taskList_Id = task.getTaskListId();
        // here is database method which is setting item value true when mark as completed on long click listener is pressed.
db.Complete_TaskList(taskList_Id); 
// Remove from List
list.remove(Position);  // Added here
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();   // Added here          
        break;
```

this will remove the item form ListView.

Comment: oh, but after uploading app again it is showing same values again, it is not updating the list. how to do that?

Comment: I thought you will do that. You should modify the code of `db.getAllTaskList()`. Here you should add where condition to get all list which having value `false` for completed column. If you didn't get share the code for `db.getAllTaskList()`